# Can Barcode Scanner API support continuous scan?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, developer, barcode

I use LWC Barcode Scanner API try to develop continuous scan feature. LWC Barcode Scanner API document as follow link:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_barcodescanner

My code for continuous scan as follow

```
     for (let index = 0; index < this.maxContinuousScanCount; index++) {
        this.scanner.beginCapture(options).then((result) => {
            var value = decodeURIComponent(result.value);
            this.scanResults.push([value]);
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.handleContinuousScanEachTime(value);
                this.playSound(true);
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.playSound(false);
                this.showFailedToast(error);
            });
            this.scanner.endCapture();
        }).finally(() => {
            this.scannerResult = this.scanResults.join('\n\r');                
        });            
    }
    this.scanner.endCapture();
```

Is this code issue or just LWC Barcode Scanner API not support continuous scan yet?

Best wishes,
Lee

Comment: I think you need to consider promises.all() for the current implementation. Since you're pushing multiple promises in loop and want them to be in sync manner, I feel that's the best option you can have. 

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/promise-all-in-javascript-with-example-6c8c5aea3e32/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not found useful idea about it. Please need check this in next Release.